# Can't reference Django database with dj_database_url

Tags: python, django

I have a Django application using decouple and dj_database_url (it is not on Heroku).  If I put my connection information in settings.ini (DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST, and DB_PORT) and set up my database connection in settings.py like this:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': config('DB_NAME'),
    'USER': config('DB_USER'),
    'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'HOST': config('DB_HOST'),
    'PORT': 'DB_PORT',
}
```

}

It works fine.

However, if I put this in my settings.ini:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://johndoe:mypassword@123.456.789.000:5000/blog_db
```

and reference it like this in my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {"default": dj_database_url.config(default=config("DATABASE_URL"))}
```

It doesn't work.  I just get a 500 when I try to run my server.  I presume there is something wrong with my syntax.  Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the traceback of this 500 error?

Comment: also: what version of Django and `dj_database_url` are you using?

Comment: All I see with the 500, when I try to go to my app is: 

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

The version for dj_database_url is 0.5.0

Comment: Any logs from starting the django server or something?